# Using a Known Nonce to Derive Private Key From Nonce, Signature and Message

Tags: typescript, elliptic-curve, ecdsa, ecdsasignature

I am trying to derive a private key using the formula below:

[image]

The inputs are:

- r & s are from the signature.
- H(m) is a hash of the message being signed.
- k is the nonce used to sign the message.

Below is my code implementation using the npm `elliptic` module, that uses BN.js. When I try and compute the key though, I am getting a very different result than the expected private key.

`sec256k1.test.ts`

```
import {
  createKeyPair,
  generateNonce,
  derivePrivateKeyFromNonce,
  toHexString,
} from '../services/keys';
import { KeyTypes } from '../types';
import { BN } from 'bn.js';

let keyPair: any;
it('can create a new key and sign with it', async () => {
  const type = KeyTypes.SECP256K1;
  keyPair = await createKeyPair(type);

  const msgHash = toHexString([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
  const signature = keyPair.sign(msgHash);
  expect(keyPair.verify(msgHash, signature)).toBe(true);
});

it('can sign using a provided nonce', async () => {
  const msgHash = toHexString([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
  const signature = keyPair.sign(msgHash, {
    k: generateNonce,
  });
  expect(keyPair.verify(msgHash, signature.toDER())).toBe(true);
});

it('can sign using a provided nonce and then derive private key from nonce', async () => {
  const msgHash = new BN(toHexString([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
  const signature = keyPair.sign(msgHash, {
    k: generateNonce,
  });
  expect(keyPair.verify(msgHash, signature)).toBe(true);
  const privateKey = keyPair.priv;
  const k = generateNonce();
  const r = signature.r;
  const s = signature.s;
  const Hm = msgHash;
  const orderOfCurve = new BN(
    '115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337'
  );

  const derivedPrivateKey = derivePrivateKeyFromNonce(
    k,
    Hm,
    s,
    r,
    orderOfCurve
  );
  expect(derivedPrivateKey).toStrictEqual(privateKey);
});
```

`keys.ts`

```
import { ec } from 'elliptic';
import { KeyTypes } from 'src/types';
import { BN } from 'bn.js';

export const createKeyPair = async (keyType: KeyTypes) => {
  const suite = new ec(keyType);
  const key = suite.genKeyPair();
  return key;
};

export const toHexString = (byteArray: number[]) => {
  return Array.from(byteArray, (byte: number) => {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xff).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('');
};

export const derivePrivateKeyFromNonce = (
  k: any,
  Hm: any,
  s: any,
  r: any,
  n: any
) => {
  const step1 = k.mul(s);
  const step2 = step1.sub(Hm);
  const step3 = r.invm(n);
  const privateKey = step3.mul(step2);
  return privateKey;
};

export const generateNonce = () => {
  return new BN('12345');
};
```

`output`

```
    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1

    - "d56da70b351cf3e485dc6065655915d51caf9e6272dc000536da06fc394199b0"
    + "607f218f9dd1a21aec11e0c877a9e54ed5912dcf06b6a66540e0cf19214236ba5ed288f7bdf81a6523775fa954b0e127ab819a76fc394eca5cdb94bf2ef7f4bab3"
```

I believe the issue is my value for H(m) being passed to `derivePrivateKeyFromNonce` but I am not exactly sure how to get it to work. Does anyone know where the breakdown is in my `derivePrivateKeyFromNonce` formula causing the derived key to be drastically different than the private key?

Comment: I didn't read through all the code but I don't see you computing an inverse mod n anywhere. When you see something like r^(-1) in the formula that means you must compute the inverse of r mod n, where n in this case is the order of the ed25519 elliptic curve group.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! I am definitely not doing this. I will plug this in and see if that fixes it.